# Is there a modulo divisor of integers that only ever gives four results?

Tags: integers

I am working on a simple script where I have a partial solution to a problem. I think it will work if I can identify a number that divides any given integer such that you only get four possible remainders (or a multiple thereof).

Is such a thing known?

Comment: How about division by $4$?

Comment: OMG, how did I not see that easy answer?